# LP into uniswap v2 when tokens are in arbitrary ratio

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I want to add liquidity in a Uniswap pool from my smart contract. The tokens are in arbitrary ratio so it will be a two step process:

1. Swap one of the tokens so they're 50:50 by price
2. Add to LP with `UniswapV2Router02.addLiquidity()`

For example I have (1 ETH, 50 USDC) and the price of ETH = 100 USDC. The total value of liquidity added is 150 USD. To LP the exact amount there should be 150 / 2 = $75 of tokens on both side. So I swap 0.25 ETH for 25 USDC such that the token ratio is (0.75 ETH, 75 USDC).

Is this the right approach, or am I missing something?